# List of StringBuilders inserting values on all lines, why?

Tags: list, matrix

So, I have a matrix like this (exclude those bullets from the beggining; I just printed it like that for a better view):

- 11121
- 11001
- 10011
- 10111
- 13111

and the following code:

```
 public void LabyrinthView1()
 {
  List<StringBuilder> newView = new ArrayList();
  StringBuilder temporar = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < matricePrincipala.get(0).length()-1; i++)
  {
      temporar.append("1");
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < matricePrincipala.size(); i++)
  {
      newView.add(temporar);
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < matricePrincipala.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matricePrincipala.get(i).length(); j++)
        {      
            if (matricePrincipala.get(i).charAt(j) == '2')
            {
                newView.get(i).insert(j, 'S');
            }

            if (matricePrincipala.get(i).charAt(j) == '3')
            {
                 newView.get(i).setCharAt(j, 'E');       
            }
        }
    }

  System.out.println("matrix newView -> " + newView);
}
```

First of all, I initiate a new matrix, with the same size as the first one (5x5) with all the elements '1'. This is done in the first two fors.

The following 2 fors are iterating through both matrix. First, I want to locate the position of the '2' element in the first matrix (which I printed earlier), and insert, on that position, but on the second matrix, the char 'S'. The same thing I do with the '3' element, and inserting 'E' in the right position.

So, in the end, what I want that System.out.println("matrix newView -> " + newView) to print is this (again, ignore the bullets):

- 111S1
- 11111
- 11111
- 11111
- 1E111

but I get this:

- 1E1S1
- 1E1S1
- 1E1S1
- 1E1S1
- 1E1S1

Why ? And clearly most important: **how can I fix this issue** ?

Answer (score 0):

You are just manipulate the same instance of `StringBuilder`, so the output is just the same.

Do use a single `StringBuilder` and append new line for each `matricePrincipala`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't clearly understand what you mean. By "manipulating the same instance of StringBuilder" you're referring to that "temporar" StringBuilder, which is declared at the beginning ?